# Custom Directives Not Loading in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an index.html file which which is very large, so I split it up into different partial html files which I want to load into an index shell file via directives. Here's the relevant part of index.html:

```
   <div north-view></div>
   <div west-view></div>
   <div center-view></div>
   <div east-view></div>
```

Then I have another file called directives.js which assigns templateUrls to these:

```
'use strict';

/* Directives */


angular.module('cstarsApp').
  directive('westView', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'partials/west-view.html'
    };
  }).
  directive('centerView', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'partials/center-view.html'
    };
  }).
  directive('eastView', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'partials/east-view.html'
    };
  }).
  directive('northView', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'partials/north-view.html'
    };
  });
```

The partial html files specified by the templateUrl bits look like this (center-view.html for example):

```
<div class="accordion ui-layout-center" id="searchResultsAccordion" ng-controller="SearchResultsController">
    SEARCH RESULTS
    <h3 class="ui-accordion-header">Search Results Word Cloud</h3>
    <div id="searchResultsWordCloud" style="width:200px; height:100px">
    </div>
    <h3>Search Results</h3>
    <div class="accordion" id="searchResultsDocumentsAccordion">
        <table id='searchResultsTable' class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">
            Some more html..
            ....................
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that this setup fails to load in the partial html files properly: it looks like the contents of the partials display on the webpage but with none of the stylings/javascript that I expect.

However, if I get rid of the custom directives and simply paste in the contents of the partials to index.html where I've specified it works perfectly. What's happening here? Is there some argument I'm missing in the return value for the directives? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If the logic isnt working, its probably not getting the controller from the scope. You need to expose it in the directive, otherwise it has no access to it. Regarding the styles- thats a bit weird. If you call $digest manually on one of the views after they load, does it work?

Comment: I think you're right in that it's not getting the controller from the scope. How exactly do I "expose it in the directive"?

Answer (score 0):

If the controller is only needed for the templates, then you should add it as a controller in the directive.

Otherwise, you need to expose the relevant part of your scope to the directive - it's usually not advisable to expose the whole parent scope.

I won't write up all the possibilities here, but I will point you in a good direction for where to learn about directives and scope:

1. http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/
2. http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals

Both of those have a 2 part tutorial which should get you started along the way.

Comment: Yes the controller is only needed for the templates. How do I "add it as a controller in the directive"? For instance center-view.html uses SearchResultsController as I've shown. What specifically do I need to add to the centerView directive to make it aware of that controller?

Comment: If you only use that controller in the directive and don't need it outside of it you can just use the directive's "require" to inject the controller. Tho I don't think that's why your styles were not showing, are they linked in the index file or in one of the directives? I think they should be in the index file.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify. Each partial html file specified by the directive uses a controller which I've defined in a separate file and added to my mainApp module. I state this ng-app at the top of my index file and yes all of my styles are linked in the index file. I tried using "require" as you suggested on the directives but that still doesn't work.

Comment: Also if I instead use ng-include to simply include the partial html files instead of the custom directives I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You miss restrict option in your code which define how do you want to invoke your directive and as you invoke your directives as an attribute you should add restrict: 'A'. you can use 'E' as well if you want to use them as an HTML tag like this

```
<west-view></west-view>
```

'E' define Element

'A' define Attribute

```
 angular.module('cstarsApp').
 directive('westView', function() {
return {
restrict: 'A',
  templateUrl: 'partials/west-view.html'
 };
}).
directive('centerView', function() {
 return {
 restrict: 'A',
  templateUrl: 'partials/center-view.html'
};
}).
 directive('eastView', function() {
return {
restrict: 'A',
  templateUrl: 'partials/east-view.html'
};
}).
 directive('northView', function() {
return {
restrict: 'A',
  templateUrl: 'partials/north-view.html'
};
     });
```

hope this will help